# Почему переменная не видна внутри функции?

Tags: php

Кусок кода:

```
require_once 'medoo.php';
$database = new medoo([
...//код
]);
$dbtext = $database->select('test0', [
 'text'
]);
$text1 = $dbtext[0]['text'];
$text2 = $dbtext[1]['text']; //получает значение из таблицы, проверял на работоспособность с file_put_contents


function sendMessage(){
globals $text1;
if ($chatText =="/start") {
     $message = "Hello!";
 }
elseif ($chatText == "Foo") {
     $message = $text1; //в данном месте переменная $text1 уже не видна
 }
else ($chatText == "Bar") {
     $message = $text2; //пременная $text2 так же не видна
 }
}
```

Я так понимаю, что напутал что то с областями видимости. Как разрешить данную проблему?

Comment: Используйте слово `global`, а не `globals`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно эдак

```
function sendMessage($chatText, $text){
    if ($chatText =="/start") {
         $message = "Hello!";
     }
     else ($chatText == "Foo") {
         $message = $text;
     }
}
```

Если надо передавать прям реально много переменных, то передавайте их массивом

```
$params = array("text"=>$text1, "id"=>$id, "text2"=>$text2 ....);
function sendMessage($params){
    ....
    $message=$params["text"];
    ....
}
```

Но лучше всего изучите работу с классами. Внутри класса в любом методе можно работать с общими для класса переменными типа $this->text1

Comment: У меня много переменных внутри функции: `$text1`, `$text2`,`$text3`,`$text4` итд.

Comment: @ioodie обновил ответ

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{'

Comment: Спасибо вам! Через массив всё работает.

Comment: @Ипатьев уважаемый, вы если правите, то делайте это так, чтоб автору(мне) не приходилось потом синтаксические ошибки в исправлениях подчищать.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, рад помочь :)

Answer (score 1):

### Единственно правильный ответ, без синтаксических ошибок и кривого кода.

Чтобы использовать переменную в функции, ее надо в функцию **передать**. Именно для этого служат красивые скобочки после имени функции:

```
function sendMessage($chatText, $text1, $text2) {
if ($chatText =="/start") {
     $message = "Hello!";
 }
elseif ($chatText == "Foo") {
     $message = $text1; //в данном месте переменная $text1 уже не видна
 }
else ($chatText == "Bar") {
     $message = $text2; //пременная $text2 так же не видна
 }
  return $message;
}
```

А если в функцию передается очень много переменных, то значит это неправильная функция, и ее надо переделать.

В данном случае явно требуется всего два параметра: передаваемый текст и карта замен

```
$trans = [
    '/start' => 'Hello!',
    'Foo'    => 'text1',
    'Bar'    => 'text2',
];
echo sendMessage($chatText, $trans);

function sendMessage($chatText, $trans)
{
    if (isset($trans[$chatText])) return $trans[$chatText];
    return $chatText;
}
```

или что-то в этом роде

Comment: Единственно правильный ответ, без синтаксических ошибок и кривого кода. function sendMessage($chatText, text1, $text2).

Comment: "Единственно правильный ответ." Передайте сюда сотню другую параметров.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ваш вариант тоже подходит. У меня небольшая путаница в следствие того что мой первый язык это JS и там области видимости немного иначе работают.

Comment: @ioodie в любом языке городить кучу ифов - это кривой код. Я дополнил ответ. Впредь рекомендую описывать в вопросе изначальную задачу.

Comment: @Ипатьев в данном случае другого варианта нет. Есть кнопки в боте Tg, и соответственно сколько кнопок - столько и elseif-ов, на каждый вариант нажатия.

Comment: @ioodie вариантов нет только у того, кто не хочет их видеть.

Comment: @Ипатьев буду рад прочитать от опытного человека, про более удобное и правильное решение, чем то что пришло мне на ум (цикл), если вас не затруднит.

Comment: @ioodie более правильное решение уже написано в моем ответе. Осталось разуть глаза и прочитать.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы переменная была видна внутри функции используется ключевое слово global (в вашем коде видимо опечатка и написано globals)

```
$testValue = "test";

function testFunction()
{

    global $testValue;
    echo $testValue;

}

testFunction(); // выведет на экран слово test
```

Comment: Вот за такое надо бить по пальцам, железной линейкой.

Comment: А потом еще десяток таких функций и человека разбирающего ваш код можно довести до самоубийства.

Comment: Автор вопроса спрашивает "Почему переменная не видна внутри функции?" Ответ на этот вопрос неверный синтасис в его коде. Он не спрашивает "Как правильно передать переменную в функцию", а интересуется почему она у него не видна.

Comment: @5f0f5048ff спасибо за ответ, но вариант с `global` не работает. Я опечатался в поле вопроса написав `globals`

Answer (score -1):

Ответ пародия! Единственный правильный ответ прочитать документацию http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list, выкинуть php ниже 5 версии и использовать конструкцию `...`

```
function sendMessage($chatText,...$arguments) 
{
}
```

что бы не возникало вопросов это типо очень сложно и не понятно пишем документацию

```
/**
 * This function send message to chat
 * @param string $chatText
 * @param string ...$arguments Text messages 
 * @return string
 */
function sendMessage($chatText,...$arguments) 
{
}
```

p.s. Не забываем выкинуть блокнитики с плюсиками и поставить нормальную idea phpstorm к примеру или netbeans

Comment: Не в кассу. До 5.6 можно было использовать func_get_args(), и в любом случае вопрос здесь не в этом - анонимные переменные автору не помогут, ему нужны именованные.